# Abel Summation Formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Out of curiosity I wanted to calculate
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n} = \ln 2 \approx 0.6931471806
$$
using Abel Summation formula
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left\{ \frac{\sum_{n\leq x} \left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{x} + \int_1^x {\rm d}u \, \frac{1-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor u \rfloor}}{2u^2} \right\} = \int_1^\infty {\rm d}u \, \frac{1-\left(-1\right)^{\lfloor u \rfloor}}{2u^2} \approx 0.6687714032 \, .
$$
So any insights in why the result is different?

Comment: What should it yield? I used $$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} u^{n-1} = \frac{1-u^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{1-u} \, .$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula

Answer (score 0):

This last integral *is* equal to your series, but there's not much of a better way to compute it:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1 - (-1)^{\lfloor u \rfloor}}{2u^2} \,du = \int_{ u \geq 1 : \lfloor u \rfloor \mathrm{odd}}\frac{1}{u^2}\,du =\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \int_{2k+1}^{2k+2} \frac{1}{u^2}\,du = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2k+2} \right).$$

How did you calculate your approximation to this last integral?

Comment: numerically in maple
`int((1-x^floor(u))/((1-x)*u^2), u = 1 .. infinity, numeric)`
where $x=-1$. You think it's a rounding issue?

Comment: Yeah, there's something weird happening with Maple, and I'm not sure what it is.  The integrand is clearly non-negative, but if you replace "infinity" with, say, 10000, then Maple gives 0.6930971831, which is closer to the correct answer.  So it's doing something weird; maybe it thinks it's converging faster than it actually is?

Comment: I don't really know either. Maybe I ask that question @mapleprimes.